# Python progress bar with a fixed size in a variable withtout print

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

From this python3 code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar("Percent of this year : ", max=100)
for i in range(int(50)):
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

I have this output printed in the console :

```
Percent of this year :  |################                | 50/100
```

The output is exactly what I need but I don't want to use it as a printed output in the console.

I need it to be saved in a variable to be writed in a file.

I want this result :

```
print(myvar)
Percent of this year :  |################                | 50/100
```

Comment: Why do you need to store it in a variable? have you considered redirecting the output to a log file like 'python filename > output.log'. ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :

```
percent = 70
barre = (
    "["
    + "#" * int((50 / 100) * percent)
    + "-" * int((50 / 100) * (100 - percent))
    + "]"
)
BarrEarth = "Percent of this year : " + (barre) + str("\n")
```